# DSolve gives invalid solution to 5 coupled differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

Solving these 5 differential equations gives an invalid solution.

```
D1 = D[f[t, c2, c1, d2, d1], t] - 
   D[h Log[(d1 - c1)/((d1 - t) (t - c1)) + (c2 - 
          d2)/((d2 - t) (t - c2))], t];

D2 = D[f[t, c2, c1, d2, d1], c2] + 
   h (((-c2 + d1) (-t + d2) (-t + c1))/((-c2 + c1) (-c2 + d2) (-t + 
          c2) (-t + d1))) + 
   2 hn (1/(-c2 + d1) - 1/(-c2 + c1) - 1/(-c2 + d2));

D3 = D[f[t, c2, c1, d2, d1], d2] + 
   h (((c1 - d2) (c2 - t) (d1 - t))/((c2 - d2) (d1 - d2) (d2 - 
          t) (c1 - t))) + 
   2 hn (1/(-d2 + c1) - 1/(-d2 + d1) - 1/(-d2 + c2));

D4 = -D[f[t, c2, c1, d2, d1], c1] + 
   h (((c1 - d2) (-t + c2) (-t + d1))/((-c2 + c1) (d1 - c1) (-t + 
          d2) (-t + c1))) + 
   2 hn (1/(-d2 + c1) + 1/(d1 - c1) - 1/(-c2 + c1));

D5 = -D[f[t, c2, c1, d2, d1], d1] + 
   h (((d1 - c2) (-t + d2) (-t + c1))/((d1 - c1) (d1 - d2) (-t + 
          c2) (-t + d1))) + 
   2 hn (1/(-c2 + d1) + 1/(c1 - d1) - 1/(d1 - d2));
```

Solution details:

```
sol1 = DSolve[{D1 == 0, D2 == 0, D3 == 0, D4 == 0, D5 == 0}, 
    f[t, c2, c1, d2, d1], {t, c2, c1, d2, d1}] // 
   Flatten;

In[15]:= sol1c = 
 Collect[f[t, c2, c1, d2, d1] /. sol1, {h, hn}] // FullSimplify

Out[15]= 1/(
 c1 - d2) ((c1 - d2) C[
    1] - (c1 - d2) (h + 2 hn) Log[
     c1 - c2] + (2 c1 - d1 - d2) h Log[-c1 + c2] - c1 h Log[c1 - d1] +
    d2 h Log[c1 - d1] + c1 h Log[-c1 + d1] - d2 h Log[-c1 + d1] - 
   2 c1 hn Log[-c1 + d1] + 2 d2 hn Log[-c1 + d1] + 
   2 c1 hn Log[-c2 + d1] - 2 d2 hn Log[-c2 + d1] + d1 h Log[c2 - d2] -
    d2 h Log[c2 - d2] - 2 c1 hn Log[d1 - d2] + 2 d2 hn Log[d1 - d2] + 
   2 c1 hn Log[-c1 + d2] - 2 d2 hn Log[-c1 + d2] - 
   2 c1 hn Log[-c2 + d2] + 2 d2 hn Log[-c2 + d2] + 
   c1 h Log[-d1 + d2] - d2 h Log[-d1 + d2] + c1 h Log[c1 - t] - 
   d2 h Log[c1 - t] - c1 h Log[c2 - t] + d2 h Log[c2 - t] - 
   c1 h Log[d1 - t] + d2 h Log[d1 - t] - c1 h Log[d2 - t] + 
   d2 h Log[d2 - t] - 2 c1 h Log[-c1 + t] + 
   2 d2 h Log[-c1 + t] + (c1 - d2) h Log[-c2 d1 d2 + 
      2 c2 d1 t - (c2 + d1 - d2) t^2 + 
      c1 (-c2 d1 + c2 d2 + d1 d2 - 2 d2 t + t^2)])

In[18]:= f1[t_, c2_, c1_, d2_, d1_] = f[t, c2, c1, d2, d1] /. sol1;

In[20]:= D1 /. f -> f1 // FullSimplify

Out[20]= 0
```

Visibly, solution does satisfy equation `D1` eqn but doesn't satisfy `D2` and the others (checked that part numerically). What is going wrong, and is there any way to get the solution?

I've seen some posts where DSolve fails, but this setup has 5 equations, so doesn't fit.

**Some insight**

In the limit $d_1 \to c_1$, the first three equations are the only relevant ones, which get solved easily, and the answer for that is

```
{f[t, c2, d2] ->  C[1] - h Log[-t + c2] - h Log[-t +  d2] + (-2 hn + h) Log[-c2 + d2]}
```

so the solution to these 5 equations better have that form in this limit, but that's so far been insufficient for me to get the function $f$.

I in fact know that
$$
\exp f= F(c_i, d_i)  \cdot  \left( \frac{d_1-c_1}{(d_1-t)(t-c_1)} + \frac{c_2-d_2}{(d_2-t)(t-c_2)}\right)^{h} \cdot B(c_i, d_i)^{h_n}
$$
The (invalid) solution Mathematica gives has a $B$ which matches the limiting solution, but $F$ part doesn't.

How can I solve for $F$?

**Edit**: The (invalid) solution was obtained on my institute's V13.0.

Comment: I get no solution from `DSolve` in V13.1. Is the code correct?

Comment: Yes, the code is correct and I do get a solution in my institute's V13.0. But a friend of mine said the same thing as you when I asked him to solve these equations for me.

Comment: Where is the typo? I can share the notebook with you actually; I have indeed checked what I have posted. Please check, I've given the solution I get from those equations, which does satisfy D1 equation

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the confusion. :) Original notation was more complicated, so I did regex substitutions in equations but forgot to do the same in DSolve, and just wrote it by hand. Check my update in a second.

Comment: The form of the solution you got is not the typical form for a general solution to a PDE. It looks more like an asymptotic approximation, but that's probably a stretch. I can't really see it. That it satisfies one equation and not another argues against it. So, it may be a bug. It's been "fixed" in V13.1, in that instead of giving an erroneous solution, `DSolve[]` gives no solution.

Comment: Can you give a reference for how general PDE solutions look like? Interestingly, I noticed that `DSolve`'s solution satisfies the equation for first variable, e.g. if I write `f[a,...]`, solution satisfies the equation with `D[f[a, ..], a]`

Comment: I'll solve equations 5 times this way, and then take thier linear combination, which on plugging in the equations should give 5 linear equations, and I guess then I might be able to solve this set of equations correctly.

Comment: The general solution $u(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is (locally) defined up to $k$ arbitrary functions of $n-1$ variables where $k$ is the order. E.g. the 1D wave equation has a general solution $c_1(t-x)+c_2(t+x)$, where $c_1$, $c_2$ are arbitrary $C^2$ functions. (When $n=1$, the PDE is an ODE and the functions are constants, that is, functions of zero variables.) Since symbolic solutions are rare in high-dimensional systems, so are statements of a general theorem. Maybe in a graduate-level book. Non-general ref: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/partial-differential-equation